# Jquery mobile listview icons not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, icons

I have a problem with the icons in a jquery mobile listview. As you can see in the picture below a question mark is showing after I've updated to the latest version of jquery mobile.

[Icons not working correctly http://jeflussenburg.nl/img/iconnotshowing.png](http://jeflussenburg.nl/img/iconnotshowing.png)

Before I updated the question marks were like arrows to the right `>`.

My HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">  
    <div id="status"></div>
    <ul id="linksList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" ></ul>
</div>
```

Javascript function for each row:

```
function renderEntries(entries) {
    var s = '';
    $.each(entries, function(i, v) {
        s += '<li><a href="#contentPage"  class="contentLink" data-entryid="'+i+'">' +                    v.title + '</a></li>';
    });
    $("#linksList").html(s);
    $("#linksList").listview("refresh");       
}
```

I've already tried adding `data-icon="arrow-r"` to the `<li` items but that didn't work. I've also updated the images map to their latest version.

**UPDATE:**
I've copied this code from the JQM docs:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Divider</li>
    <li data-icon="home"><a href="#">data-icon="home"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="delete"><a href="#">data-icon="delete"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="plus"><a href="#">data-icon="plus"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="arrow-u"><a href="#">data-icon="arrow-u"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="arrow-d"><a href="#">data-icon="arrow-d"</a></li>
    <li data-icon="check"><a href="#">data-icon="check"</a></li>
</ul>
```

After testing it i saw that the icons are actually showing BUT theres a question mark icon showing over them. Where does this question mark icon come from? And most importantly how do I get rid of it?

Any help is very appreciated!

**Solved:**

Seems like it that it was a bug. After updating to the latest JQM build 1.1.1, those question marks disappeared and everything works like it used to.

Comment: Just a suggestion: You can post an answer and mark that as the correct answer instead of appending a "solved:" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit old now but this might help someone since I recently had the same issue. Looks like you were missing the images directory from inside www/css
There should have been a folder www/css/images with these 5 images in it:

```
ajax-loader.gif     icons-18-white.png  icons-36-white.png icons-18-black.png   icons-36-black.png
```

The jquery full package zip (JavaScript, CSS, and images) has them in it.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I hope this might help someone as confused as me find their solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `data-icon="arrow-r"` to the `<a>` items according to [the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response! `s += '<li><a href="#contentPage" data-icon="arrow-r" class="contentLink" data-entryid="'+i+'">' + v.title + '</a></li>';` edited like this, but it's still showing a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it that it was a bug. After updating to the latest JQM build 1.1.1, those question marks disappeared and everything works like it used to.